# "Sudo without password" does not work

Tags: sudo, password

I want to enable a user to run sudo without password. I used `visudo` to append the line to config file

```
idiot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Yet sudo still asks password as usual. Why?

Comment: Add the output of `sudo -l`.

Comment: because you have space between `NOPASSWD:` and `ALL` - change it to `idiot ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL` and it should be fine

Comment: I have removed the space, but after `sudo -k` it still wants a password.

Comment: is idiot a group or a user? If it's a group, the member of `idiot` must log out/login first. If it's a user - is `idiot` member of other groups, which require password for sudo?

Comment: Thanks, I have found the problem. It was `/etc/sudoers.d` folder not empty, it overrode my config. Thanks for `sudo -l` tip, it tipped me off.

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved. I assumed that the line

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Is commented out, because the symbol in the front. But no, it is still working and overriding my config. 
You should add your changes after the line or check the contents of `/etc/sudoers.d` directory.